# Copy entire folder to IsoStorage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

For my Windows Phone application I am currently copying my files to the isostorage by listing the exact files.

```
string[] files = { "index.html", "style.css", "jquery.js" };
foreach (string f in files)
{
    Uri fileUri = new Uri(componentPrefix + f, UriKind.Relative);
    StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(fileUri);

    if (sr == null) 
    {
        // we are probably a folder or non-existing file
    }
    else
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.Stream))
        {
            byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sr.Stream.Length);
            IsoStoreUtils.SaveToIsoStore(f, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to copy an entire folder instead of listing the files I want copied?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a foreach loop, but you need to gather a list of all embedded resources first. You can retrieve them by using [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx).

Comment: I am not getting GetManifestResourceNames to return a correct list of resources. Can you post an example?

Comment: *just found out GetManifestResourceNames returns a file containing the resources. Can you still post and example? :P